# Syntax error using Mako

Tags: python, mako

I'm new to Python and Mako and I'm learing to use it. I've obtained the 0.7.0 version of it and have tried to import it in the interpreter and I'm getting the following error. Not sure where to go from here.

```
>>> from mako.template import Template
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
 File "/home/kumaram/python/Mako-0.7.0/mako/template.py", line 295
 @util.memoized_property
 ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Does anyone have any ideas why this would come up and what can I do about getting rid of it. BTW, I've mako on the $PYTHONPATH too.

Thanks, K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you have a Python version that predate decorators, you need to upgrade Python.

Comment: Thanks. From which version of python is this supported?

Comment: Decorator syntax was added to Python 2.4, so 2.4 or later is required.